# Change Model After Code First Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I enabled Code First Migration but after sometime I changed the model properties so when i ran the application the following error is given.

Invalid column name etc...because after migration i changed the model.

So far I understand the problem is that I updated the model but these changes don't apply to database table...kindly help me to fix it..means model properties and database column don't match

Migration is enabled.
I set automatic migration to true but i doesn't work.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5AMU.png)

```
public class Floor
{
    public int FloorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set;}
}


public class Room
{
    public int RoomID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Room Rent")]
    public decimal Rent { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Floor")]
    public int FloorID { get; set; }

    public int Seater { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Attach Bathroom")]
    public Boolean AttachedBathRoom { get; set; }

    public virtual Floor Floor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CNIC { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Floor")]
    public int FloorID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Room No")]
    public int RoomID { get; set; } 

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Floor Floor { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify your primary and foreign keys in your classes.

To specify a primary key, add `[Key]` before your key attribute. For a foreign key, you also have to add the table it is linked to. So in your Room class you would have something like this:

```
[Key]
[ForeignKey("Floor")]
public int FloorID { get; set; }
```

Do the same for all your keys in all your models.

Then, you need to add a new migration and then update your database.

In your Packet Manager Console, type this to add a new migration:

```
Add-Migration FooBar
```

Then update your database with this command:

```
Update-Database
```

Comment: I got the following error after executing your given command                    "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Rooms'. Only one identity column per table is allowed". in package consol manager.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your FloorId in Rooms is a foreign key, right ?

Comment: Yes FloorID is foriegn key.